# Setting iframe ng-src value from ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to set iframe ng-src value from ng-model. Here is my HTML code.

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController">
         <label>Enter the URL: <input type="text" ng-model="url"/></label><br />
<iframe width="900" height="400" ng-src="{{url}}"></iframe>
```

Here is my app.js code

```
 .controller('simpleController',function($scope,$sce){
    $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
 }
```

For the first time when i load the page , it is working properly, means in the iframe box it is displaying the mentioned URL, but once i change the input text box with some other URL, it is throwing error,

```
Can't interpolate: {{url}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

Can any one help me to solve the problem. Is it possible to declare **$sce.trustAsResourceUrl** globally. or can we use $watch function on **$scope.url** variable. please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: We cant without that. It will throw same error. Whenever you change URL it has to go through **$sce.trustAsResourceUrl**

Comment: when you are using angularjs and iframe, we have to use **$sce.trustAsResourceUrl**